# Need to know iPhoto Library location programmatically using Applescript

Tags: python, applescript, iphoto

One of my desktop apps I need to know where the iPhoto Library is installed, programmatically. I do not want to pick it from predicted location (/Users/me/Pictures/iPhoto) since power user may have installed it somewhere else.

I'm developing app using Python and I guess Applescript might have way to figure out iPhoto location but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply...

```
set myPath to path to application "iPhoto"
```

Comment: Often the simplest answers are the best - not sure why this is not the accepted one.  Also if the path is required with `/` separators instead od `:`, then use this `set myPath to POSIX path of (path to application "iPhoto")`

Comment: The poster asks for the location of the iPhoto Library

Comment: DigiMonk, Where do you see that? "need to know where the iPhoto is installed"

Comment: He's writing: " I do not want to pick it from predicted location (/Users/me/Pictures/iPhoto)". So I assumed "the iPhoto" means the library :)

Comment: DigiMonk is correct. I need to fetch all photos stored inside iPhoto (/Users/me/Pictures/iPhoto Library.photolibrary).

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use 'defaults'.

Applescript:

```
set lib_path to do shell script "defaults read com.apple.iphoto LibraryPath"
```

Should be similar way to do it straight from Python.

A downside to this is if Apple changes the format of iPhotos preference file in the future and it breaks.

Comment: Works for iPhoto, but not necessarily with other apps.  Try iTunes, for example.

Comment: Better (and correct) way to use 'defaults' is : set iPhotoLibraryFilePath to (do shell script "defaults read com.apple.iphoto LibraryPath") (no grep needed)

Comment: Thanks @DigiMonk have simplified answer based on this

Comment: @Nilay Anand, wondering why have you un-accepted this answer 4 months later? Has it stopped working for you and the new accepted answer suddenly started working?

Answer (score 0):

Simply invoke the system command `which iPhoto` (assuming that you can run iPhoto from a shell) and parse the output.

Comment: What happens in a terminal if you type `which iphoto` - sorry I don't mac so not sure what the case might be.

Comment: I typed `which iphoto` on terminal and it didn't output anything. I'm using OS X 10.8.5

Answer (score 0):

[Removed LaunchServices-based answer as OP apparently wants the location of the iPhoto *Library*, not iPhoto itself.]

OP should look into Karelia's [iMedia framework](https://github.com/iMediaSandboxing/iMedia) ([dev forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/imedia-dev)), which includes iPhoto support. The Karelia crew have also done a lot of legwork in figuring out how to make it sandbox/AppStore-compatible, which may also be a consideration depending on how the OP plans to distribute the app.